# What is the actual hex value of Brightness.dark in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to change the color of the status bar to the same color as theme Brightness.dark

```
ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
)
```

What hexadecimal value can I change the statusBarColor to reflect the color of Brightness.dark?

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
```

I tried the below which  did not work

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(Brightness.dark)
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I would suggest you research material design guidlines. They mostly contain the hex values. E.g on Android you can see the code on this page: https://material.io/archive/guidelines/style/color.html#color-themes

Comment: @EnviroApps Thanks! That was helpful!

Comment: glad I could help you